Old documentary about human evolution
It was a documentary (maybe from BBC or some Canadian educative TV) about human evolution (Australopithecus, Homo habilis, Homo erectus, etc).
I believe it was not a single chapter but a short series.
It had a guy (maybe an archeologyst) that explained things like stone tools, and most of the times he was wearing a hat (like those cowboys hats).
I am Brazilian and I saw it around 80's end or beginning of 90's, it was at that time exhibited at our TV Cultura, but it may be older than that.
It had a very cool openning with a cool music where it showed that traditional animated drawing of a primitive man walking and evolving to homo sapiens.

Can it be The ascent of Man? :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ascent_of_Man

Gustavo thanks for the edit and the suggestion but it is not this show (The Ascent of Man is amazing for sure). But it was very similar to this one.

You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Try looking at this list, and see if any are familiar. https://letterboxd.com/windyblue/list/early-humans-documentaries/

I believe you are looking for Walking with Cavemen(2003):

Walking with Cavemen is a four-part television documentary series about human evolution produced by the BBC in the United Kingdom. It was originally released in April 2003. It was subsequently presented in the United States as a two-part series by the Discovery Channel and its affiliates. There was an accompanying book of the same title.
Like previous Walking with... documentaries, Walking with Cavemen is produced in the style of a nature documentary, featuring a voice-over narrator (Robert Winston in the British release, Alec Baldwin in the North American release) who describes the recreations of the prehistoric past as if they were real. As with the predecessors, this approach necessitated the presentation of speculation as if it were fact, and some of the statements made about the behaviour of the creatures are more open to question than the documentary may indicate. The style is different in UK and US versions, as Robert Winston travels through time to the location of drama taking place, while Alec Balwin remains ever in the present day in a lit room with skulls representative of ancestral hominid species highlighted in each drama.
Each segment takes the form of a short drama featuring a group of the particular hominid in question going about their daily lives (the search for food, protecting territory, and caring for the sick and injured). The intent is to get the human viewer to feel for the creatures being examined, almost to imagine being one of them (a trait that the documentary links to the modern human brain).
In the first episode, we see Australopithecus afarensis, and focus on their evolved bipedality. The story follows the famous Lucy and her relatives, as they first develop a leadership conflict following the death of the alpha male due to a crocodile attack, and then are attacked by a rival troop. The attack ends with the death of Lucy herself, and her eldest daughter caring for Lucy's now-orphaned baby sibling, as a sign of the developing humanity in these "apemen".
The second episode leaps forward to a time when Paranthropus boisei, Homo habilis and Homo rudolfensis co-exist. H. habilis is depicted as an intelligent omnivore that is more adaptable than the herbivorous P. boisei. The two species are contrasted, with H. habilis being "a jack of all trades", while P. boisei are "a master of one" - i.e. they are specialized herbivores while H. habilis are generalized omnivores. Consequently, though P. boisei are able to eat termites, tall grasses and hard acacia pods in difficult times, they will not be able to survive in the future, when at the beginning of the next Ice Age the climate will change, and these plants will be gone for good. H. habilis, on the contrary, have become smart by eating fresh carrion and bone marrow among other things, and evolving a basic social behavior, which is more firm than that of P. boisei, will continue to survive, until it evolves into Homo ergaster, seen in the next episode, who has developed these traits to a greater extent.
In the third episode, Homo ergaster is depicted as the first creature to master the art of tracking. This was made possible because their diet has grown increasingly more carnivorous, and the nutrients in meat made them even smarter than H. habilis of the previous episode. They also begin to form into tribal societies, with genuine bonds between their men and women, though violence is still occurring. As no longer use his arms to walk or climb trees, the muscles of his chest enables them to issue particular sounds, a primitive language.
The episode later shows H. ergaster spreading into Asia, becoming Homo erectus and encountering the enormous herbivorous ape Gigantopithecus, "the original King Kong".
However, for the next million years, H. ergaster is still very much an animal, following its instinct, but then, they are shown harnessing fire and beginning to break-away from their direct dependence on their environment.
The fourth episode first shows Homo heidelbergensis in Britain. H. heidelbergensis is depicted as intelligent and sensitive but lacking in the ability to comprehend an afterlife, or anything that isn't in the "here and now".
Next, the episode shows a clan of Homo neanderthalensis, how they lived and hunted, including the mighty mammoth during the last ice age. Finally in Africa then we see Homo sapiens idaltu which are not adapting well in Africa's drought unlike the Neanderthals in the north, along with them we see modern Homo sapiens, who had to become imaginative and inventive to survive the long drought unlike their subspecies idaltu, and finally glimpse the cave painters of Europe, who had "evolved" the idea of the afterlife and the supernatural, and now ready to start the human history as it is now known, and drive the Neanderthals to extinction.

I could be wrong, but I think this is what you were talking about.

The OP says they saw it in the 80s or 90s. This show is from 2003.

That is why i said I could be wrong

now worries though, can be fixd

It is not this one, but thanks. I just want to find for nostalgic reasons only :)

Ohhh ok no worries XD

How many parts do you think it had in it?
